# Rendering Problems....Update Android studio but dont; get it solved

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Rendering Problems The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout 
(Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)

Tip: Try to build the project.

Android studio 1.2.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have couple of options to try

1. First manually build the project, then manually sync the project (using the Sync with Gradle files in the toolbar, or from the Tools > Android menu), then finally press Refresh in the toolbar above the layout editor.
2. Switch the Android Gradle plugin 1.2.3 .

> To do so , you can goto your PROJECTS's build.gradle file and update the classpath to like below

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
  }
}
```

3. Try updating to Android Studio 1.3 Canary.

[Official Link](http://tools.android.com/knownissues#TOC-Can-t-Render-Layouts-in-Android-Studio-1.2)